# How to draw a circle of lines

Tags: ios

I want to basically make a dashed circle matching values from 0-100. I don't want to get 10 different images representing a different 10 point increment. How can I do it?

[image]

Something like this

Comment: Tried `UIBezierPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom subclass of UIView.

Override drawRect.

In it, you will use these functions:

- UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext
- CGContextBeginPath
- some line drawing functions
- CGContextClosePath
- CGContextDrawPath

If you look up the documentation of those functions, you'll quickly find cross-references to the functions you need.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not at home in iOS or Objective-C, the concept is universal.

The position of any point on a circle can be described as `sin(angle)*radius,cos(angle)*radius`. Therefore you can draw a circle like this yourself by following this concept (in pseudocode):

```
drawCircle(radius, borderWidth, dashDensity)
{
    int numberOfDashes = radius / dashDensity);
    float radsPerDash = pi * 2 / numberOfDashes;
    float innerRadius = radius - (borderWidth / 2);
    float outerRadius = radius + (borderWidth / 2);

    for(float angle = 0; angle < pi * 2; angle += radsPerDash)
        DrawLine(sin(angle)*innerRadius, cos(angle)*innerRadius,
                 sin(angle)*outerRadius, cos(angle)*outerRadius);
}
```

You should be able to get it to look like you want from here. You can of course also calculate `dashDensity` automatically from the `radius` using a magical constant, and use line width as you see fit for thicker dashes.

For a semi-circle (for example 85% filled), change the end condition of the loop:

```
for(float angle = 0; angle < (pi * 2 * 0.85); angle += radsPerDash)
```

Comment: Very helpful. However I ended up doing a custom bezier path. Then i set the color, line pattern (dash) and the fill accordingly to achieve this effect

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say [rtm](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) here, but do it. Create the circle with `CGPathCreateMutable` and `CGPathAddArc`, then use `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath`. Done.