# How to draw a gradient dashed circle like (IOS Game Peak Brain Score Screen)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to draw a gradient dashed circle like (IOS Game Peak, Peak Brain Score Screen), a dashed circle from red to green.

[image: https://baking.ieasynote.com/images/IMG_0071.jpg]

Thanks.

Comment: Provide some code and show what you have tried so far or AT LEAST a screenshot showing in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, i take back the "screenshot"-part since you just malformed the question body and there actually was an image.

Comment: `code` CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Sprites/circle.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(kDirectorSize.width/2, kDirectorSize.height-64-18-kSpriteCircleWidth/2);
        sprite.color = kGreenColor;
        [self.contentNode addChild:sprite];

Comment: Maybe i can use CCProgressNode to do it.       `code`  CCProgressNode *progress = [CCProgressNode progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Sprites/circle.png"]];
        progress.type = CCProgressNodeTypeRadial;
        progress.position = _taskSprite.position;
        progress.percentage = 82;
        progress.color = kBlueColor;
        progress.scale = kDirectorSizeRatio;
        [self.contentNode addChild:progress];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CCProgressNode *rogressNode = [CCProgressNode progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Sprites/circle.png"]];
    progressNode.type = CCProgressNodeTypeRadial;
    progressNode.position = ccp(160, 220);
    progressNode.percentage = 75;
    progressNode.color = [CCColor colorWithUIColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addChild:progressNode];
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to draw a circle of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100159/how-to-draw-a-circle-of-lines) 
This will help you since it is not using cocos2d but concept of drawing circle is same. you can use `ccBezierConfig`in cocos2d.